use a priority queue to do hierarchical clustering without import heapq
I am using priority queue to do the hierarchical clustering(can not import heapq), and want to use the complete-link method, but I don't know what is the problem of my code, the reason is far from what I expected...by the way the data I use to cluster is 1095 documents which are stored in a data folder.
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
import os
import numpy as np

porter_stemmer = PorterStemmer()


script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
txt_folder_path = os.path.join(script_dir, 'data') 
output_folder = os.path.join(script_dir, 'output')
sw_path = os.path.join(script_dir, 'stopwords.txt')
docfreq = {}


with open(sw_path, 'r') as sw:
    stopwords = set(sw.read().splitlines())


txt_files = [f for f in os.listdir(txt_folder_path) if f.endswith('.txt')]
N = len(txt_files)

for filename in txt_files:
    file_path = os.path.join(txt_folder_path, filename)
    
    
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        data = f.read().lower()
        
        adjusted = [word for word in data.split() if word.isalpha() and not any(char.isdigit() for char in word)]
        text = " ".join(adjusted).split()
        filtered_sentence = [w for w in text if w not in stopwords]
        stemming = [porter_stemmer.stem(w) for w in filtered_sentence]
        termfreq = {}
        totalword = len(stemming)
        unique_words_in_doc = set(stemming)
        
       
        for word in unique_words_in_doc:
            docfreq[word] = docfreq.get(word, 0) + 1
                
        for word in stemming:
            termfreq[word] = termfreq.get(word, 0) + 1
        for word in termfreq:
            termfreq[word] /= totalword

        
        termfreq_file_path = os.path.join(output_folder, filename)
        with open(termfreq_file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as termfreq_file:
            termfreq_file.write(f"{'term':<20}{'termfreq':<20}\n")
            for term, freq in sorted(termfreq.items()):
                termfreq_file.write(f"{term:<20}{freq:<20}\n")
        
sorted_terms = sorted(docfreq.items(), key=lambda x: x[0].lower())
result = [[i, doc, freq] for i, (doc, freq) in enumerate(sorted_terms, 1)]


def log(x, base):
    return np.log(x) / np.log(base)

index_mapping = {term: i for i, (term, _) in enumerate(sorted_terms, 1)}

for filename in txt_files:
    file_path = os.path.join(output_folder, filename)
    termfreq = {}
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        next(f)  
        for line in f:
            parts = line.split()
            if len(parts) == 2:
                word = parts[0]
                try:
                    tf = float(parts[1])
                    termfreq[word] = tf
                except ValueError:
                    continue

    tf_idf = {}
    for word in sorted(termfreq.keys()):
        df = docfreq.get(word, 0)
        if df > 0:
            tf = termfreq[word]
            idf = log(N / df, 10)
            tf_idf[word] = tf * idf

    tf_idf_file_path = os.path.join(output_folder, filename)
    with open(tf_idf_file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as tf_idf_file:
        tf_idf_file.write(f"{'t_index':<8}{'tf-idf':<20}\n")
        for term, value in sorted(tf_idf.items()):
            index = index_mapping.get(term, 0)
            tf_idf_file.write(f"{index:<8}{value:<20}\n")


def load_tfidf_vector(doc_filename):
    tfidf_vector = {}
    file_path = os.path.join(output_folder, doc_filename)
    
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        next(file)  
        for line in file:
            parts = line.split()
            if len(parts) == 2:
                term_index = int(parts[0])
                tfidf_value = float(parts[1])
                tfidf_vector[term_index] = tfidf_value
    
    return tfidf_vector

def cosine(Docx, Docy):
    vec_x = load_tfidf_vector(Docx)
    vec_y = load_tfidf_vector(Docy)
    
    all_indices = set(vec_x.keys()).union(set(vec_y.keys()))
    
    x_vector = np.array([vec_x.get(i, 0.0) for i in all_indices])
    y_vector = np.array([vec_y.get(i, 0.0) for i in all_indices])
    
    dot_product = np.dot(x_vector, y_vector)
    norm_x = np.linalg.norm(x_vector)
    norm_y = np.linalg.norm(y_vector)
    
    if norm_x == 0 or norm_y == 0:
        return 0.0
    
    return dot_product / (norm_x * norm_y)

def hierarchical_clustering(documents, num_clusters):
    N = len(documents)
    C = np.zeros((N, N))  # Similarity matrix
    I = [1] * N  # Indicator: 1 = active, 0 = merged
    clusters = {i: [i] for i in range(N)}  # Initialize each document as its own cluster

    # Compute initial pairwise similarities
    for n in range(N):
        for i in range(n + 1, N):  # Only compute for i > n
            similarity = cosine(documents[n], documents[i])
            C[n][i] = similarity
            C[i][n] = similarity  # Symmetric

    # Perform hierarchical clustering
    for _ in range(N - 1):  # Perform N-1 merges
        # Find the most similar clusters to merge
        max_sim = -float('inf')
        i, m = -1, -1

        for x in range(N):
            for y in range(x + 1, N):   
                if I[x] == 1 and I[y] == 1 and C[x][y] > max_sim:
                    max_sim = C[x][y]
                    i, m = x, y

        # Merge clusters
        clusters[i].extend(clusters[m])
        clusters[m] = []  # Clear the merged cluster
        I[m] = 0  # Mark cluster m as merged

        # Update similarities for the merged cluster
        for j in range(N):
            if I[j] == 1 and j != i:  # Update only active clusters
                new_sim = min(C[i][j], C[m][j])  
                C[i][j] = C[j][i] = new_sim  # Update similarity matrix

        # Stop if the desired number of clusters is reached
        if sum(I) == num_clusters:
            break

    # Extract the final clusters
    final_clusters = [sorted(clusters[key]) for key in sorted(clusters.keys()) if len(clusters[key]) > 0]
    return final_clusters

def save_clusters_to_file(clusters, k, cluster_folder):
    file_name = f"{k}.txt"
    file_path = os.path.join(cluster_folder, file_name)

    with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for cluster in clusters:
            cluster = sorted(cluster)  # Sort doc IDs in ascending order
            f.write("\n".join(map(str, cluster)))  # Write cluster separated by empty line

    print(f"Clustering results saved to {file_path}")

# Create cluster folder if it doesn't exist
cluster_folder = os.path.join(script_dir, 'cluster')
os.makedirs(cluster_folder, exist_ok=True)

# Perform clustering and save results for k=8, k=13, k=20
for k in [8, 13, 20]:
    clusters = hierarchical_clustering(txt_files, k)
    save_clusters_to_file(clusters, k, cluster_folder)

I want it to correctly clustering for 8,13,20 clusters.and the result will be saved in a txt. like the image I attached.

Why can't you import heapq?

There's no image.

You have to give us more information than that. What part of your code is not working? Have you run the program in the debugger? Debugging is an important skill. You would benefit from https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.
